# Spectrum of 4th order discretized Laplace operator

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, laplacian, finite-volume-method

Consider the Laplace operator over a 1D domain, with homogeneous Neumann boundary conditions. I have discretized this operator using the cell-centered Finite Volume method on a uniform grid of size $h$, employing a four-point central difference scheme in the bulk of the grid, while reverting to a two-point scheme near the boundaries. The result is the following matrix:
\begin{equation}
L_n = \frac{1}{24h}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        -24 & 24 &  & & & &\\
        25 & -51 & 27 & -1 & & &\\
        -1 & 28 & -54 & 28 & -1 &\\
        &\ddots &\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots\\
        & &-1 &28 &-54 &28 & -1\\
        & & &-1 &27 &-51  &25\\
        & & & &  & 24 & -24
    \end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}.
\end{equation}

Since it is a discretization of a negative semi-definite operator, I would expect $L_n$ to have real, non-positive eigenvalues. This is indeed what I observe numerically (regardless of size), but I'm struggling to prove it due to the inconvenient properties. Matrix $L_n$ is singular, asymmetric and its Gershgorin disks don't confine its eigenvalues to the left complex half-plane (we get a disk of radius $\frac{58}{24h}$ centered around $-\frac{54}{24h}$). The things that I have been able to prove, are the following:

- The vector $[1\dots 1]^T$ is an eigenvector of $L_n$, corresponding to eigenvalue 0.
- The smallest version of $L_n$ that contains the repeating stencil, $L_5$, has demonstrably real, non-positive eigenvalues (an exact expression for the characteristic polynomial can be derived & plotted).
  \begin{equation}
  L_5 = \frac{1}{24h}
  \begin{bmatrix}
          -24 & 24 &  & &\\
          25 & -51 & 27 & -1 &\\
          -1 & 28 & -54 & 28 & -1\\
          &-1 &27 &-51  &25\\
          & &  & 24 & -24
      \end{bmatrix}.
  \end{equation}
- The four-point scheme yields a negative semi-definite matrix when using periodic boundary conditions (an exact expression for eigenvalues can be derived, by leveraging the circularity of the resulting matrix $\tilde{L}_n$).
  \begin{equation}
  \tilde{L}_{n}= \frac{1}{24h}
  \begin{bmatrix}
          -54 & 28 & -1  & & & -1& 28\\
          28 & -54 & 28 & -1 & & & -1 \\
          -1 & 28 & -54 & 28 & -1 &\\
          &\ddots &\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots\\
          & &-1 &28 &-54 &28 & -1\\
          -1& & &-1 &28 &-54  &28\\
          28& -1& & &  -1 & 28 & -54
      \end{bmatrix}.
  \end{equation}

Does anyone have a suggestion for how I could go about proving the realness and non-positiveness of the eigenvalues of $L_n$? My hunch is that adding more rows with the repeating stencil somehow doesn't affect the bounds of the spectrum, but I don't know how I could prove this. I get the feeling that I might be missing a piece of theory here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe related. Elouafi, Mohamed. "An eigenvalue localization theorem for pentadiagonal symmetric Toeplitz matrices." Linear algebra and its applications 435.11 (2011): 2986-2998.

Comment: You can split the matrix into a central petadiagonal matrix, which is negative definite, and top left part and right bottom part, then probably show adding the two parts will not affect much. However, there is cross-talk between them, though very weak. That probably makes things nasty. The core idea probably is to show $vL v^t \le 0$, and split the vector $v$ into 3 parts.

Comment: Indeed, I've observed numerically that $\Re(v^* L v) \leq 0\ \forall v\in \mathbb{C}^n\ s.t. \lVert v\rVert = 1$. I'm currently constructing a proof for this and it seems doable. However, this still leaves the realness of the eigenvalues to be proven.

Comment: I would be interested in seeing your proof for the positiveness. @Nicola

Comment: In the process of constructing above said proof I found a very useful decomposition of $L_n$ into the product of a positive definite and negative semi-definite matrix. With this, the realness and non-positivity of the eigenvalues can be proven directly! I will add the proof as a solution to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found the answer to my own question! Let:
\begin{align}
    M_{n} &= \begin{bmatrix}
        -1 & 1 & & \\
        1 & -2 & 1 \\
        &\ddots & \ddots &\ddots & \\
        & & 1 &-2 & 1\\
        & & & 1& -1
    \end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}.
\end{align}

Then, $L_n$ can be decomposed as follows:
\begin{align}
    L_{n}
    &= \frac{1}{h}M_n + \frac{1}{24h}\begin{bmatrix}
        0 &  &  & & & &\\
        1 & -3 & 3 & -1 & & &\\
        -1 & 4 & -6 & 4 & -1 &\\
        &\ddots &\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots\\
        & &-1 &4 &-6 &4 & -1\\
        & & &-1 &-3 &3  &1\\
        & & & & & & 0
    \end{bmatrix}\\
    &= \frac{1}{h}M_n + \frac{1}{24h}
\begin{bmatrix}
        0\\
        & -M_{n-2}\\
        & & 0
    \end{bmatrix}M_n\\
    &= \underbrace{\frac{1}{h}\left(I-\frac{1}{24}\begin{bmatrix}
        0\\
        & M_{n-2}\\
        & & 0
    \end{bmatrix}\right)}_{Q_n}M_n.
\end{align}

Both $Q_n$ and $M_n$ are symmetric and the Gershgorin circle theorem tells us that $Q_n$ has eigenvalues of strictly positive and $M_n$ of strictly non-positive real part. Since 0 is an eigenvalue of $M_n$ (eigenvector $[1\dots1]^T$), we conclude that $Q_n$ is SPD and $M_n$ is SNSD. The eigenvalue problem for $L_n$ can thus be manipulated as follows:

\begin{align}
L_n x = \lambda x\ &\leftrightarrow\ Q_n M_n x = \lambda x\\
&\leftrightarrow\ Q_n M_n Q_n z = \lambda Q_n z\\
&\leftrightarrow\ z^* Q_n M_n Q_n z = \lambda z^* Q_n z\\
&\leftrightarrow\ (Q_n z)^* M_n (Q_n z) = \lambda z^* Q_n z\\
&\leftrightarrow\ \frac{(Q_n z)^* M_n (Q_n z)}{z^* Q_n z} = \lambda.
\end{align}

Since $M_n$ is SNSD and $Q_n$ is SPD, we conclude that $\lambda$ must be real and non-positive, QED.

Comment: pretty nice proof and seem can be generalized to other high order discretization of Laplace.